# How to handle Button Color on click in Calendar Carousel in Flutter

Tags: calendar, flutter, widget

I'm using the calendar carousel [calendar carousel](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel) widget for flutter. I'm trying to click on a random date on the calendar and change the button color and keep this color, but now I can not get this behavior. This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:father_home_flutter/model/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart'
    show CalendarCarousel;

class ScreenCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenCalendarState createState() => new _ScreenCalendarState();
}

class _ScreenCalendarState extends State<ScreenCalendar> {
  static String noEventText = "No event here";
  String calendarText = noEventText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _markedDateMap.add(
        new DateTime(2019, 1, 25),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 1, 25),
          title: 'Event 5',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ));

    _markedDateMap.add(
        new DateTime(2019, 1, 10),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 1, 10),
          title: 'Event 4',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ));

    _markedDateMap.addAll(new DateTime(2019, 1, 11), [
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 1, 11),
        title: 'Event 1',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 1, 11),
        title: 'Event 2',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 1, 11),
        title: 'Event 3',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
    ]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Календар',
            style: Constants.myTextStyleAppBar,
          ),
          iconTheme: Constants.myIconThemeDataAppBar,
          elevation: Constants.myElevationAppBar,
          backgroundColor: Constants.myAppBarColor,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Card(
              child: CalendarCarousel(
            weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            weekFormat: false,
            selectedDayBorderColor: Colors.green,
            markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
            selectedDayButtonColor: Colors.green,
            selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
            todayBorderColor: Colors.transparent,
            weekdayTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            height: 420.0,
            daysHaveCircularBorder: true,
            todayButtonColor: Colors.indigo,
            locale: 'RUS',
            onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
              this.setState(() => refresh(date));
            },
          )),
          Card(
              child: Container(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        calendarText,
                        style: Constants.textStyleCommonText,
                      )))))
        ])));
  }

  void refresh(DateTime date) {
    print('selected date ' +
        date.day.toString() +
        date.month.toString() +
        date.year.toString() +
        ' ' +
        date.toString());
    if(_markedDateMap.getEvents(new DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day)).isNotEmpty){
      calendarText = _markedDateMap
          .getEvents(new DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day))[0]
          .title;
    } else{
      calendarText = noEventText;
    }
    }
  }

  EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>(events: {
    new DateTime(2019, 1, 24): [
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 1, 24),
        title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, '
            'sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
            ' \n\nUt enim ad minim veniam,'
            ' quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.'
            ' \n\nQuis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. '
            'Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      )
    ]
  });

   Widget _eventIcon = new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1000)),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.person,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  );
```

and the current behavior:

[image]

Using these parameters seems to not work as I'm looking for:

```
 selectedDayBorderColor: Colors.green,
 selectedDayButtonColor: Colors.green,
 selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to change the splash color, you may need to override it from current theme, try to wrap your calendar carousel widget in a `Theme` and override the `ThemeData` as it follows:

```
 Theme(data: ThemeData(
      splashColor: Colors.green,
    )
    child: YourCarouselWidget(),
);
```

Also, make sure you are updating the selected day with your `setState` on the `onDayPressed` property.

Comment: yes, you are right, I was not properly using the onDayPressed.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this problem I did as @miguelpruivo suggested, fixing the onDayPressed on this way:

```
 onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
              this.setState(() => refresh(date));
            },

void refresh(DateTime date) {
    _currentDate = date;
```

also in the CalendarCarousel parameters:

```
selectedDateTime: _currentDate,
```

and bellow the _ScreenCalendarState declaration:

```
  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.now();
```